# R: Suppressing renv project startup message

Tags: r, renv

Typically, when starting up an [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/) project, one gets a message that looks something like this:

```
* Project '~/path/to/project' loaded. [renv 0.10.0]
```

I am trying to suppress this message, particularly when non-interactively running a script from this project.

Checking the package help, I noted `?config` i.e. *User-Level Configuration of renv*. Specifically, I found `synchronized.check`, of which the document states is for controlling how renv lockfile synchronization is checked (this is also outputted to the console). However, I couldn't find how to control the main startup message. I also checked the `?settings` but found nothing relevant either.

I've tried fiddling with `options` and `Sys.setenv` without luck so far.

So, is it possible to suppress the message, seeing that the renv script `activate.R` controls how the package itself is loaded?

Comment: Have you tried *options(verbose=FALSE)* ?

Comment: Yes, I have and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there isn't a specific documented way to configure this in `renv`. For now, you can set:

```
options(renv.verbose = FALSE)
```

before `renv` is loaded. (You may want to turn it back to `TRUE` if you want `renv` to display other messages as part of its normal work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress library startup messages with *suppressPackageStartupMessages*, e.g.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(igraph))
```

There is also *suppressMessages* for arbitrary function calls.

Comment: renv is loaded with boilerplate code, notably a file named *activate.R*. I am looking to controlling this behavior from, say `.Rprofile` so that if I load the project from the command line, the message doesn't show. `suppressPackageStartupMessages` can't be used in this situation.